# Alternative to NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

Currently I have a `UITableView` with its data source being an `NSFetchedResultsController`. The most important thing the `NSFetchedResultsController` does is automatically update my table if there are any changes, via delegate methods. However, I no longer need to do a fetch to get my entity, call it `"Pictures"` for now. I have another entity called `Folder`, and `folders` have a relationship with `Pictures`, so every `folder` has an `NSSet pictures`.

So instead of fetching all `pictures` that belong to a certain `folder`, now I can just do `folder.pictures`, and that returns what I need, and I can assign that to an array and set that as my `tableView` source. However, this doesn't give me automatic table updates like an `NSFetchedResultsController` would.

My question is how can I have the functionality of an `NSFetchedResultsController` (that is, the delegate methods that automatically update my table) without executing a fetch? I don't need to fetch anymore since I have an `NSSet` with the desired `NSManagedObjects`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with the fetched results controller? Just keep it and use the dot notation for relationship sets as well - you get the best of both worlds.

The real advantage of the fetched results controller is actually hidden. It will fetch your objects (`folders`) alright - but maybe it will not fetch all the relationship attributes (`pictures`). This is called faulting. It means that core data will get the data in the background if it is needed. It is automatically optimized for speed and good memory usage. For example, the potentially huge array of your datasource will not have to be all in memory at once, something that is unavoidable with an array.

Thus, you really do not want to get rid of the FRC. She is your friend. Stay faithful to her. ;-)

Comment: Wait so there's a way to fetch an entire set of an Entity?

Comment: Well, yes, exactly as you would do it otherwise. Say you have fetched an instance of `folder` for one row of your tableview - you can now simply access `folder.pictures` as usual.

Comment: So my fetched results controller would only have 1 object, the folder, and for my table view number of rows, I would do folder.pictures.count?

Comment: I thought you have many folders, one for each table row. In that case, tell the fetched results controller to fetch the pictures instead. Limit by folder with an `NSPredicate`.